# Button.Visible = true; fails to set the button to visible when activated within a function

Tags: c#, winforms

I haven't been able to find anyone else having this same problem, so hopefully someone might have some ideas or be able to point me to another answer.

When a function is run by pressing a button on the form, another button should become visible.  However, the button never shows up even though it is the first thing in the function.  All of the other code in the function works perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
private void trackbar_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.Visible = true;
    progressbar.Visible = true;

    ...

    progressbar.Visible = false;
    button.Visible = false;
}
```

The progress bar shows up and works fine, and all other code in the function works fine as well, but the button never shows up at all.

If I remove `button.Visible = false;` from the end of the function, then the button DOES show up, but only after all other code has executed.  Like this:

```
private void trackbar_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.Visible = true;
    progressbar.Visible = true;

    ...

    progressbar.Visible = false;
    //button.Visible = false;
}
```

Commenting out that line causes the button to show up.  Now if I add a message box after the button line, then it also works.

```
private void trackbar_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.Visible = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Button should be visible now");
    progressbar.Visible = true;

    ...

    progressbar.Visible = false;
    button.Visible = false;
}
```

Adding the message box after the button line caused the button to show up at the right time.

Does anyone have any ideas why this button is behaving this way?

Comment: Short answer, no.  this is strange indeed... can't wait to hear an answer.

Comment: during `trackbar_Change()`, the UI is not going to update unless it's blocked by something like putting up a message box. You'll need to hide the button somewhere else. (Perhaps, on progresscomplete of the progress bar?)

Comment: You're showing it, then hiding it again...what exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: The code within the `...` takes around 15 seconds to complete.  Also the progress bar is also hidden at the end and functions properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like the GUI thread is busy. Try forcing the screen update by calling [Application.DoEvents()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx), for example:

```
button.Visible = true;
progressbar.Visible = true;
Application.DoEvents();
```

`DoEvents()` will force all the message in the message queue to be processed.

A **better solution** would be to move the long running thread of main UI thread.  Use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for the task.

It will make the form more responsive overall. For example you would be able to interact with the form and it won't turn 'white'.   Implementing the BackgroundWorker is simple and a must for long running processes on the main UI thread,

Comment: It would be best to not even suggest `DoEvents()`.

Comment: @JeffMercado, I totally agree that `DoEvents()` is not the proper way.  But better that the OP is made aware of it and contrasted with the correct approach instead of stumbling on DoEvents and then not have the wider context.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to _mention_ it only to say it's something you should never use. It's important to understand why it should be avoided. But when you give code examples showing its use, you're setting a trap for people who don't know any better who copies the first bit of code they see. So I'm just saying be careful with that.

Comment: @PhilipFourie Thanks, the BackgroundWorker solves more problems than I knew I had. Now the progress bar works better as well.

Comment: DoEvents was the only possible solution for me on a windows CE 5 device with .NET CF after trying both backgroundWorkers and threads. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're executing a long running process on the UI thread and so setting the button to visible won't happen until the thread is free. However, by the time the thread is free you have set visible to false.

The best way to do this is to execute the long running process on a background worker so that the UI thread isn't blocked.  And the reason the progress bar works is because it runs on a different thread.

There is one other way -- but probably less correct -- and that's to issue a Refresh on the form after setting visible to true.

Let me know if you need help with the BackgroundWorker but it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a Windows Form, it creates the new form, which then waits for events to handle. Each time the form handles an event, it processes all the code associated with that event. All other events wait in the queue. While your code handles the event, your application does not respond. For example, the window does not repaint if another window is dragged on top.

If you call DoEvents in your code, your application can handle the other events.
Use `Application.DoEvents();`

Answer (score 0):

You have this kind of behavior if your controls are inside a container like a panel, and you try to change the visibility of the control when the container control has visibility set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using a child form embedded in a panel on the parent form.  I resolved it by adding the control visibility code of the child form to the Form_Shown event on the parent form.