# Setting Button visibility to false code behind

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a list of buttons around 100. I'm setting visibile to false in aspx page and then when needed I'm trying to set visibility to true from code behind.

I cannot do Button1.Visible = true; (where Button1 is the Id of the button because there are about 100 buttons)

Is there any other way to set visibility to true from code behind? I'm creating a  function which will accept the Id of the button and then I want to set visibility to true.

Comment: I think this is duplicate question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441084/button-visible-true-fails-to-set-the-button-to-visible-when-activated-within

Comment: If you had included your current set of code with which you are working now, it'd be easier for SO to point you out in the right direction. Certainly you can loop through forms controls collection and manipulate the property for controls which is based `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Display:none" instead of "Visible = false" like below code.

```
Button1.Style.Add("Display","none"); // for hide
Button1.Style.Add("Display","block"); // for show
```

This will hide your button from screen.

Also another way if you want to do on Design page instead of Code behind you can write your condition like,

```
<% if("your condition") {<%>
 //enter your HTML part here
<%} else{%>
// HTML
<%}%>
```

Use of this you can hide your button from design screen too.

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons are in some parent control with `runat="server"`, then you can get the collection of controls from there in the `Controls` property of the parent control. Then you can check if the control is `Button` or not and then you can set `Visible = "false"` from the code behind.
Example: if you have buttons inside a `div` with `id="div1"` then you can code like below

```
foreach (var c in div1.Controls)
    if (c is Button)
       (c as Button).Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle it from the client side is better.You just put some class names along with the buttons you want to show or hide. Suppose your buttons class name is 'myClassName'.
Then write a style as shown below

```
.myClassName
{
    display:none;
}
```

Then remove the visible=false property from the button and put the class instead of it. Then write the javascript method as shown below.

```
function ShowButtons()
{
    $('.myClassName').show();
}
```

Then call the below line of code from your code behind. It will call the javascript method from the code behind.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","ShowButtons()",true);
```

Try this one.